# Finding a minimum spanning tree with only white edges (if exists) in a graph with black and white edges

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I have recently been doing some research into algorithms for finding minimum spanning trees in graphs, and I am interested in the following problem:

Let $G$ be an undirected graph $G=(V, E)$, $c(e)$ is black or white for each edge $e$ and weights $1\leq W(e)\leq 100$ for each $e$.

I want to find if we have a minimum spanning tree with only white edge in graph $G$.

My solution is to give each white edge $0$ weight and run Prim's algorithm.
We will add to a new parameter $w=0$ the weight of each edge that we adding to the minimum spanning tree. After the end of running prim's algorithm, we will check if ($w>0$) return false, else return true.

Is it can work?
Is there something more efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just remove all of the black edges from the graph and run a normal Prim algorithm, the black edges are useless. (in other words, disregard black edges, treat black edges the same way you treat non-existent edges).

Comment: PS:I use kruskal most times, instead of Prim.